# how to get time from datePicker and run method in this time ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, datepicker

i want to get time from datePicker into NSDate object, and then to run a method every day in this time.
for example: 
the user put in the datePicker the tome 08:00 and every day in 08:00 the application will run some method.

Thank you very much,
Amir Foghel

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or are you expecting someone to write the code for you?

Comment: Yo do understand that, when you build this, the code will only be ran if the user has the app open. Apple prohibits code to be executed in the background by apps

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the time from datepicker use ,

```
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"]; //24hr time format
NSString *dateString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.myDatePicker.date];
[outputFormatter release];
```

To do a functionality at particular time daily use [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Set the repeatInterval as NSDayCalendarUnit.

And in the delegate to handling the UILocalNotification code your method.

**NOTE:** This method will be execute only when the user accepts the Local notification.